# 0x API - "PancakeSwapFeature/UnderBought"?

Tags: web3js, 0x

```
{"code":105,"reason":"Error","values":{"message":"PancakeSwapFeature/UnderBought"}}
```

I was trying to swap ETH to BUSD via [direct swap](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api-starter-guide-code/blob/master/src/direct-swap.js) on BSC . Approval on ETH was set to MAX_UINT for 0x exchange proxy on BSC, so allowance shouldn't be an issue and I made sure there was enough balance before querying

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue related to slippage as discussed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/etherscan/comments/mun54r/comment/gv6spqr/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3). Try adjusting the [slippagePercentage](https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/api-references/get-swap-v1-quote) parameter as discussed in the [troubleshooting guide](https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/guides/troubleshooting-0x-api-swaps#slippage-tolerance).